# a C++ template question: choose the unexpect function

Tags: c++, templates

I am writing my list like the std::list so I have functions like this:

```cpp
template <typename _Tp>
class list {
public:
    // ...

    iterator insert(iterator __pos, const _Tp &__val) {
        // ...
    }
    template <typename _InputIter>
    iterator insert(iterator __pos, _InputIter __begin, _InputIter __end) {
        if (__begin == __end) return __pos; 

        // here I use the *__begin... so ...
        iterator __ret = insert(__pos, *__begin);
        while (++__begin != __end) insert(__pos, *__begin);
        return __ret;
    }

    iterator insert(iterator __pos, size_t __cnt, const _Tp &__val) {
        // ...
    }
}
```

this is the main function

```cpp
int main() {
    tinystd::list<int> mylist;
    tinystd::list<int>::iterator it;
    it = mylist.begin();

    // error happens here
    mylist.insert(it, 2, 20);
}
```

It seems like the compiler will choose the function `template <typename _InputIter> iterator insert(iterator __pos, _InputIter __begin, _InputIter __end)` and cause an error says that `indirection requires pointer operand ('int' invalid)`

I want to know why this happens and how to modify it.
Thank U so much ^^

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Because the 2nd `insert` wins in overload resolution; given `mylist.insert(it, 2, 20);` the template parameter `_InputIter` could be deduced as `int` and then it's an exact match. On the other hand, the 3rd `insert` requires an implicit conversion from `int` to `size_t`.

You can use [`std::input_iterator`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/iterator/input_iterator) (since C++20) to specify that `_InputIter` must satisfy the requirements as an input iterator.

```
template <std::input_iterator _InputIter>
iterator insert(iterator __pos, _InputIter __begin, _InputIter __end) {
    // ...
}
```

Before C++20 you can impose restrictions on `_InputIter`, e.g. must be usable with `operator*`.

```
template <typename _InputIter, std::void_t<decltype(*std::declval<_InputIter>())>* = nullptr>
iterator insert(iterator __pos, _InputIter __begin, _InputIter __end) {
    // ...
}
```

Comment: Thank you so much! It works perfectly.

Comment: "*e.g. must be usable with `operator*`*" This constraint seems too loose (`std::optional` also has `operator*`), shouldn't be `is_convertible_v<typename std::iterator_traits<_InputIter>::iterator_category, std::input_iterator_tag>`?